# C++ Control When cout Flushes

Tags: c++

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to have `cout` 'flush' itself only when I explicitly tell it to. I know this can be achieved by 'buffering' the contents we want to write into a `string` or a `stringstream`, but I'm looking for the most efficient way of doing this.

Also it would be nice to also be able to eat up trailing newlines in this buffer. I've seen solutions that writes `\b` to `cout`; however I'm pretty sure this is unreliable due to flushing (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: The right solution is to use std::stringstream or equivalent buffer. std::cout is just a convenience wrapper around stdout.

Comment: Maybe implement your own [streambuffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) that doesn't flush? But i agree with the previous commenter that the "correct" solution would be to use a string stream and then output that when complete.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `stringstream`, your best bet it so prevent the two most common ways that lead to an automatic flush: when you are outputting something and when you explicitly call `<< std::endl`. You can deactivate the first by setting the `unitbuf` flag of [`std::ios_base::fmtflags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags). This, though, won't likely stop the automatic flush when a new line is encountered. If your OS decides it needs to flush at every `\n` character, there's nothing you can do (on the standard C++ side).

Therefore I'd recommend manual buffering.